# Node/Express + async/await + new Mongoose {useMongoClient: true} = Mocha Test failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I updated an API I'm working on with async/await instead of callback. The API worked well with and without the transformation.

I build it TDD-like with Mocha/Chai and all my tests were OK.

But every time I launched my service I saw this message about MongoDB connection on my term.

> DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`
>   Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.

I look online and saw that I have now to add this option :  `useMongoClient: true`

So from :

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI[app.settings.env], (err, res) => { ... })
```

To :

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI[app.settings.env], {useMongoClient: true}, (err, res) => { ... })
```

But now all my test with DB search failed.

If I revert back without the option, everything is working.

Any idea why ?

Comment: May be your hitting this bug https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399

Comment: The workaround (using `useMongoClient: true`) is worse than the "bug", which is merely a warning.

Comment: @robertklep Thank... it's exactly this... I'm reading the thread to see if there is a fix !

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI[app.settings.env], {useMongoClient: true}, (err, res) => { ... })
```

to

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI[app.settings.env], {useNewUrlParser:true}, (err, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for taking the trouble to answer this question. Your answer would benefit from some narrative explaining why your changed version is preferable. Thanks.